# Python Array issue - string indices must be integers not tuple

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider the following code:

```
handInformation = [
"Thumb"[
"MetaCarpal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]], 
"Proximal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]],
"Intermediate"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]],
"Distal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]]], 

"Index"[
"MetaCarpal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]], 
"Proximal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]],
"Intermediate"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]],
"Distal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]]], 

"Middle"[
"MetaCarpal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]], 
"Proximal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]],
"Intermediate"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]],
"Distal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]]], 

"Ring"[
"MetaCarpal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]], 
"Proximal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]],
"Intermediate"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]],
"Distal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]]], 

"Pinky"[
"MetaCarpal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]], 
"Proximal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]],
"Intermediate"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]],
"Distal"["start"[0,0,0], "end"[0,0,0], "direction"[0,0,0]]]]
```

I am being hit with a type error `string indices must be integers, not tuple`

It has been some time since I last used Python and previously always worked with NumPy however here I am not.

Essentially the data I am trying to capture is three sets of three values for each bone, in each finger, on each hand.

If anyone can explain why the error occurs, and any way to solve it (preferably without the use of NumPy, but I am open to suggestions) it would be appreciated.

**Edit**

I hope to access the data with something similar to:

```
        for finger in hand.fingers:
            for x in range(0,4):
                bone = finger.bone(x)
                value1 = handInformation[finger][bone][0]
                value2 = handInformation[finger][bone][1]
                value3 = handInformation[finger][bone][2]
```

Comment: What do you expect `"start"[0,0,0]` to do? `"start"` is a string and you are trying to index it with the tuple `0,0,0`.

Comment: The same then applies to `"MetaCarpal"[...]`, which in turn is supposed to be an index for `"Thumb"[...]`.

Comment: The same then applies to `"MetaCarpal"[...]`, which in turn is supposed to be an index for `"Thumb"[...]`.

Comment: I wanted a memorable name for that array rather than 0,1,2 etc to reference it later. Perhaps this is just a simple mistake of just creating an array called start[] rather than a string?

Comment: You are welcome to create a memorable name such as start. The problem is that you aren't using any variable named start - you are using a string.

Comment: I notice several downvotes, and  two votes to close, anybody mind telling me whats wrong with the question? It may be an easy fix but as far as I can tell this isn't a duplicate or a poorly explained question..

Comment: @cricket_007 Would this require defining a separate array for each "name" I wanted to give, or would they be defined by just removing the speech marks around them?

Comment: I'll gladly answer if you can briefly explain how you would like to access this data. Arrays of arrays is really not a preferred data structure for this.

Comment: Please see edit. Thanks!

Comment: And the downvotes are probably because the problem is pretty obvious for any language where you can index a string. `"hello"[0,0,0]` doesn't make any sense... `"hello"[0]` does

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't realise "obviousness" was a bad quality for questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting downvoted almost certainly because your code syntax is wrong - "string"[0,0,0] isn't a valid construct in Python.

You could use dictionaries, with not dissimilar syntax like this:

```
handInformation = {
"Thumb":{
"MetaCarpal": {"start":[0,0,0], "end":[0,0,0], "direction":[0,0,0]}, 
"Proximal":{"start":[0,0,0], "end":[0,0,0], "direction":[0,0,0]},
"Intermediate":{"start":[0,0,0], "end":[0,0,0], "direction":[0,0,0]},
"Distal":{"start":[0,0,0], "end":[0,0,0], "direction":[0,0,0]}
} #end of thumb
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for providing some some useful feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the other answer with the data in dictionary format, you can access the data like so

```
for finger, fingerInfo in handInformation.items():
    for bone, boneInfo in fingerInfo.items():
        start = boneInfo['start']
        end = boneInfo['end']
        direction = boneInfo['direction']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are a gent.